# Rails 4 show action result and execute following action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, action, message

i have the following requirement for an identification request via the estonian mobileID system:

1. on the rails app, user clicks on button, creating a request to the id database, which also generates a transaction control code
2. on the rails app, control code is shown on the view
3. user verifies that the control code is the same with the one they are now receiving on the phone, and if valid user enters pin on the phone
4. the rails app now needs to query the id database for a result of the interaction user phone <> id database system
5. depending on the state a result is rendered

I have the backend working, however, i am confused about the flow in the rails app. I currently have the following action in my controler:

```
def id_user
  @user = current_user
  #create a new object for identification request & call MobileIdServce method to invoke the sending of a request
  @identification = MobileIdService.new(current_user).send_request
  flash[:notice] = "Control Code: #{@identification[:challenge_id]}"

  # on this point i tried both, render and redirect to a separate action
  render action: "show"

  #redirect_to({ action: 'check_request_status', session_code: @identification[:sesscode] }, notice: "Control Code: #{@identification[:challenge_id]}")
  #here starts the request status check
  check_request_status(@user,@identification[:sesscode])
end

private

# I also tried to implement this as a separate action before, but i think a private method is more appropriate

def check_request_status(user,session_code)
  @user         = user
  @session_code = session_code
  MobileIdService.new(current_user).check_request(@user, @session_code)
end
```

In both cases (1. two actions, the first redirects to the second, 2. the first calls the private method) i have the problem that i need to manipulate the view in order to show the control code.

If i go through the procedure, the control code shows, only successfully after the actions finish, as a notice.

Is there any good practice on how to approach this?

I'm a bit at the depth of it. I would gladly go to have a single action (user sends requests) with a single resulting view (users sees control code), but from a UX standpoint i cannot expect the user to actively start a second action a la "click here to check your request status". This needs to be automatic.

Comment: So, your problem is that `flash[:notice]` is not show immediately?

Comment: yup. and my assumption is that it's because the view is in that sense not rendered again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled for the following scenario.

1. User submits a request via a form to a GET action on the user controller that renders a js partial.
2. this action 'send_id_request' creates the request against the external service and returns the control code to the js partial
3. once the js partial is rendered and executed, it automatically calls a seconde GET action on the user controller 'check_id_request_status'
4. this action starts a finite loop server-side to check on the status of the request, and renders another js partial with the result

i'm currently thinking that it might make sense to actually run the loop client-side, so that it can be killed by the user, if they want to cancel the request. otherwise there is no good way to kill the loop on the server-side.

but yeah, so far so good.